# Steel or Aluminum?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am making a device with a cross section of plate aluminum that is 24”L x 4”W x 1/2”T. This plate is upright so it is 24”W x 4”H x 1/2”D and rides up and down on bearings on axles.
The issue is that two 1.75” round tubes will be threaded into the aluminum at each end to 10”L and bear up to 200lbs at 6” away from the face plate. Am I going to experience torsion with 1/2” aluminum plate or should I be thinking Steel plate.
The problem is that this is used in a medical device with very vulnerable (strength compromised) patients and ***failure is simply not an option***.
Suggestions?

Comment: Consider to add a sketch or similar drawing to further clarify your design and problem.

Comment: how do you thread a tube into a block of metal?

Comment: If you cannot yourself perform a stress analysis on the device as designed, and prove that it cannot fail from external stresses, you will find it absolutely impossible to get UL/CSA approval on it as a medical device: you should *not* be the one designing it.

Comment: Any engineer would do diagrams, see https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/54699/10902

Comment: @SolarMike I like to refrain from calling people "engineers" or "not engineers"; unless we're talking about qualifications, "engineering" is an activity that people can do, not a kind of person. Although for a medical device I would like to have someone with the qualification...

Comment: I'm happy to call some farmers engineers as they show a lot of common sense and skills when repairing things and solving problems.... Can also be applied to many other people who exhibit the skills. No diagrams yet though.