# I’m Building a Tower…

Tags: manufacturing-engineering

I’m contracted to hang 4x 112 lb wind generator on the top of 40’ articulating poles (1 ea.). For aesthetics it have to use a single post tower and powder coat bits of it to look good (REALLY?)
What I have to work with is a 2.5” x 1/4 seamless tube and it has to lay over by articulating at the base through an offset capsule hinge with hydraulic assist using a cable and winch connected at 28’(**Yes, really!**). The issue of flex, in reliably frequent 60 to 105mph winds, has come up. My suggestion is to add 2”x 6’ x 1/4” steel wings at graduated levels working the way around the pole on two sides with overlap of all four at intermittent points. (Think Dubai Tower) This is acceptable to the contractor if I powder coat the wings in bright colors (to be determined). The addition of a 6lb aluminum blade fixing trolley was a late add on. I took over this project from a much wiser man than I and would love to hear your take on how this works out for me in the long run?
Details: braided cables x 3 near the top and midway down are anchored into 280lb concrete buried anchors and the bottom 12’ of wing flairs out to 3” because of the articulating hinge that will allow the entire tower with generator to be laid over for repairs and maintenance. The hinged base is anchor bolted into 1280lbs concrete pour.   I’m backing it with a 10 year work (not materials) guarantee). If this sounds shadier to you than it does to me give me your opinion (*with helpful suggestions only please*)

Comment: I assume a PE has signed off on the design.  If not, I would stay away from it since you'll probably be around when it falls over.

Comment: Without diagrams to give better detail, this is one to avoid.

Comment: Any engineer would do diagrams, see https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/54698/10902

Comment: What exactly is your question? We cannot realistically answer "How this works out for me in the long run?"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.